# How to disable sensors on-demand to reduce power consumption?

Tags: battery-life, kernel, sensors

Nowadays, any Android device has a big sensor amount implemented. It is true that most of the sensors do not require a considerable amount of power for their operation. But the sum of the power consumption of the whole sensor set may be noticeable.

I already saw, some of the sensors are written/read through SPI interface by using linux SPI driver

So, is it possible to access the SPI driver at runtime to make sensors enter off/disabled/idle state to reduce power consumption? More specifically, I want to write/read SPI bytes through sysfs or command line

This should be achieveable in any rom, being rooted or with a custom kernel

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, this site is primarily for end-users of Android. I assume you found the page on [AOSP - Sensor Batching](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/batching) Not sure if you are speaking about a stock device, rooted device or custom ROM.

Comment: I think the answer would be kernel and device specific mostly. It would be best if you mention the device, Android ROM and kernel you are using. And sorry for misjudging your question and closing it earlier. :)